# How to filter a powerapps database based on one dropdown comparing to multiple columns

Tags: powerapps

Having trouble filtering a database by a series of columns. I'm not even sure how to accurately summarize what I'm looking for, which is why I haven't been able to find the right information most likely. So here's the setup and pseudo-code as I understand it:

I have a dropdown list with a series of Counties listed:

County A

County B

County C

etc

However, in the excel sheet I was given as a database, each County is broken up into a column, and any county that applies to the object in that row, is given an X mark.

What I need, is for Database to filter by whether the column that matches the value of the Counties dropdown has an X or not, and then display those objects that do.

But I'm not even sure how to word that into a question to ask the internet.

Thanks for any tips related

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the value selected from dropdown to multiple columns.It should go something like

```
    Filter(Table,col1=Dropdown.Selected.Value And col2=Dropdown.Selected.Value)
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question but I think you might want to explore the 'Visible' properties. This will allow you to select County A, B, C, ect and once you select the certain county, it will then show addition fields that you allowed based on the visible property that you added.